# Getting attachment from Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've got some existing code that retrieves calendar API data and attachments.  Works fine in most cases but I've got one customer where the information retrieved by the API is different from what I expect.  For example, attachment json will look like this:

```
"attachments":  [{
                "fileUrl":  "?view=att&th=14e8bf3a200af3a9&attid=0.1&disp=attd&realattid&zw",
                "title":    "DSG WH - 001- AGE - 20150727.pdf",
                "iconLink": ""
            }]
```

I am used to my attachmentns having a field called "fileId" which I use to construct an url for www.googleapis.com/drive/v3... which works.  However I don't know what to do with this fileUrl.  What is the exact server name and path that should precede this example, to make a Url that will work?  I've tried every combination of www.googleapis.com and docs.google.com I can think of and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

[`fileUrl`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) is the URL link to the attachment while [`fileId`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) is the ID of the attached file. Read-only. Also based from this [blog](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/attach-google-drive-files-to-calendar.html), you need to pass this information into an event modification operation using the Calendar API. Example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?supportsAttachments=true

{
  ...
  "attachments": [
   {
      "fileUrl": "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/9oNKwQI7dkW-xHJ3eRvTO6Cp92obxs1kJsZLFRGFMz9Q/edit?usp=drivesdk",
      "title": "Workout plan",
      "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"
   },
   ...
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I am not trying to create a calendar entry or attachment, just read one.  The FileUrl I am getting is "?view=att&th=14e8bf3a200af3a9&attid=0.1&disp=attd&realattid&zw".  What do I do with this?  I tried appending this to "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/" but that does not yield a working Url.  What is the correct domain name/path that I should append this partial Url to?

Comment: I am getting the same issue :(  Also have no idea.